# Apex class tried to execute in anonymous window

Tags: apex, class, developer-console, execute-anonymous

I am beginner in Salesforce and still in initial steps in understanding the concepts..i tried the below class and the output didn't come as expected

```
public class mytest2 
{
    Public integer marks;
    Public string result;
        {
        if(marks >= 35 && marks <= 50)
        result = 'passed';
        else if (marks >= 51 && marks <= 70)
        result = 'B';
        else if (marks >= 71)
        result ='A';
        else 
        result = 'failed';
                {
                  system.debug('Your results:' + result);
                }
        }    
}
```

and executing it in anonymous window

```
mytest2 c1 = new mytest2();
c1.marks = 55;
system.debug(c1);
```

Output was

> Your results:failed

which seems to be wrong

Answer (score 5):

You've inadvertently written a fairly rare construct called an [*instance initialization block*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm#!):

```
    {
    if(marks >= 35 && marks <= 50)
    result = 'passed';
    else if (marks >= 51 && marks <= 70)
    result = 'B';
    else if (marks >= 71)
    result ='A';
    else 
    result = 'failed';
            {
              system.debug('Your results:' + result);
            }
    }
```

This code runs only at the time the class is instantiated, i.e., `new mytest2()`. At that point the variable `marks` has no value and is `null`.

You will probably want to define a method here instead of your initializer block. This is covered in the documentation linked above. Also consider completing the [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) module on Trailhead.

Additionally, you should always use curly braces to delimit the scope of your control statements (`if`/`else`). Doing otherwise leads to difficult-to-interpret logic and inscrutable bugs when the compiler does not group statements as you expect it to.